# Export xls file to xml with existing xml schema

Tags: excel, xlsm, export-to-xml

I am having a xlsm file and I need to export one sheet from that file to an xml file. I am having a predefined xml schema and i have to do it from the command line.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything e.g. with `vbscript` to automate Excel from command line.

Comment: no i have not tried it...and to be honest, i am not that familiar with vbscript. is it possible to automate the process using vbscript.

Comment: One example amongst many: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: Thanks! But this isn't really the problem. I found a third party software which can convert a xls to xml through the command line. But I need to create the xml with a specific schema. Can i read the schema in the script?