# Can we send a reminder email using excel vba even when sheet is not open but computer having the sheet is on?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically It is kind of Order Management System which will have list of all orders. What I need is all the subscribers should get a email for active orders on regular basis but for this excel sheet should be opened once in a day. Can this thing work without even opening excel sheet. Is there any way I can implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

When you open an Excel spreadsheet it will open one of the worksheets.

You can write some VBA in there to execute when the workbook is opened.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Autorun App as Application
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Do your stuff here
End Sub
```

The code in the middle should set an event on a timer (for when to send the emails) and then have a separate routine to send the emails.

You can also set your computer to open the excel spreadsheet automatically when you turn it on. Then there is nothing to forget.