# getting file path in access to open and for the report contained within to run

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an access database where I have multiple records that have different file paths that are linked to individual reports that are in excel.  I need to have Access open, then for each report/file path to open in excel and for the code within the excel spreadsheet to run.  I know that I can use task manager to get Access to open but how do I get access to open each excel file, allow for the excel file to run the code, close, go on to the next and continue until all the reports have run and then finally close Access?

Comment: It sounds to me like you should instead run this inside of Excel and just query the Access database to get the filenames

Comment: I want to be able to kick everything off with one task in task scheduler.  Depending on the report, some might be run daily, weekly, or just monthly.

Comment: I think I would still recommend Excel be the 'main' application for this, but here's some reading to consider for task scheduling macros https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: thanks. i'll keep that in mind.  I have over 50 different reports and a variety of different versions as well that I need to run and they vary with regards to which days they need to run. Trying to avoid setting up a large amount of tasks to complete this. Will be harder to manage 100 or so reports eventually.