# How to run Excel Macro at a specific time automatically everytime

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is used to clear sales of my transaction in Excel, what i want is every night at a specific time (example 9.00PM) it automatically run this macro so i dont have to do it manually everyday. Is it possible to do that ? can someone help me thanks

this is the clear sales macro

```
Sub clearSales()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rConstants As Range

lastRow = Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rConstants = Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("A2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rConstants.ClearContents
Sheets("2barang").Range("B10").Value = 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
Application.Ontime TimeSerial(21, 0, 0), "clearSales"
```

Before end Sub

As long as your excel-application is active it wil run at 9:00

Answer (score 0):

If not by using  `TimeSerial`, you should perhaps think of TaskScheduler? 
Look here for more info: [Recurring schedule for xlsm file via TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler)